# exception in insert value in sqlite database android

Tags: android

i want to insert default value in database table

and i am using and put text string below:

> INSERT INTO song_text VALUES(1,'Tell me girl, what's it gonna be I
>   want you, baby do you want me You got me going insane, I'm losing my
>   mind Is your love true, or am I wasting my time',1);

but it is giving exception:

> 12-02 14:11:37.860: ERROR/Database(568): Failure 1 (near "s": syntax
>   error) on 0x247be8 when preparing 'INSERT INTO song_text
>   VALUES(2,'Tell me girl, what's it gonna be

please give any solution..
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to escape the apostrophes:

```
INSERT INTO song_text VALUES(1,'Tell me girl, what\'s it gonna be I want you, baby do you want me You got me going insane, I\'m losing my mind Is your love true, or am I wasting my time',1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should escape characters for your String, since for *what's*, it understands you have finished your String. Thus you should use: what\'s.

To be generic, you can use a method to replace all ' to \'. For example you may use:

```
private String convertString(String x) {
    return x = x.replace("'","\'");
}
```

Hope this helps!